# Keeping text to a specified line amount

Tags: html, css

How would I go about making it so that a header stays 2 lines throughout each responsive layout? For example if I put

get offers

sent to you

Is there a way to keep it so that those words are always on those lines? Currently once the layout expands the words will go to a single line, or more than 2 lines. I have tried line breaks in the html but this results into too wide of a gap in between the words that doesn't seem to be changeable through just css.

Comment: Can you expound on your last sentence?  Do you mean a gap between the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean inside a header.  Does this work?

```
    <h2>

      <div>
        get offers
      </div>
      <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
        sent to you
      </div>

    </h2>
```

Comment: Wow so simple haha. Worked perfectly I was looking at it too complexly, pretty new to web. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help.  Please mark as answer if this solves the problem.